# Finding Volume of a Triangular Region with Area of the Base

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I was evaluating the double integral, $$\iint_D y^2 \,dA\\$$ where the vertices of the region are (0,1), (1,2), (4,1). I set up my integral and got a volume of $\frac{11}{3}$.
$$\int_{1}^2\int_{y-1}^{-3y+7} y^2 \,dxdy = V\\$$
If the area of the base region on the xy- plane can be represented by the integral,
$$\int_{1}^{2} (-3y+7)-(y-1) \,dy = A$$
is there a way to use the area of the base to find the volume of the solid region? My first thought that there might be some integral L which when multiplied by the area of the base should give the correct volume of $\frac{11}{3}$.

Comment: The weighted area is in the triangular base is
$$
\int\int y^2 dx dy
=\int_0^1 dx \int_1^{1+x} y^2 dy+
\int_1^4 dx \int_1^{-x/3+7/3} y^2 dy
$$
$$
=\int_0^1 dx \frac{x(3+3x+x^2}{3}
-\int_1^4 dx \frac{(x-4)(x^2-16x+79}{81}
=\frac{11}{12}+\frac{11}{4}=11/3.
$$
To define volumes, you need triple integrals, and I don't see how you've defined a shape/boundary for something of that kind.